# iOS ViewController only support portrait but popup support all orientation

Tags: ios, orientation, viewcontroller

Is it possible to support all orientation for popup (UIAlertController) which pops from the view controller, which is only supporting portrait right now?

Now I have viewcontroller support only portrait but the popup for this viewcontroller not to be landscape.

Help me.

Comment: have you change info.plist for only portrait mode?

Answer (score 1):

If you have added UIAlertController to the portrait only view controller then i don't think this alert controller only can support all orientations since its added as a child of that view controller so it has to abide the parent.

Whereas if UIAlertController common to Application level then there may be possibilities to support any orientation.

Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: I couldn't find the solution. Maybe you're right. So we just transform the view as device's orientation. Thanks!